# How can I get all the tree graphs given a certain numbers of nodes? Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I was wondering is there a way to obtain all the different trees using Networkx? It's a known fact that the number of trees with `n`  nodes is `n^(n-2)` (using Cayley's Formula) so if there is 3 nodes, then it has 3 tree graphs, if it has 4 nodes then it has 16 trees and so on. What I want is to code all the trees using the prufer sequence, I know that Networkx has a function to create random trees, but there is a chance I can get duplicates, all I can think of is use Numpy so I can find all the unique elements in a list, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

n = 3  #Number of nodes
aux = []
prufer = []

for i in range(10):
    aux.append(nx.random_tree(n))    

for j in aux:
    prufer.append(nx.to_prufer_sequence(j))

arr = np.array(prufer)
newarr = np.unique(arr, axis = 0)
```

The problem here it's that I generated 10 random trees, but in the end I only want 3 but when I want to find all the trees using 4 nodes I don't want to generate 50 if I'm only going to use 16. Is there a way I can do this more efficiently? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  might be a bit bruteforcy, and there might be built-in functionality or a more elegant approach that I am missing, but it certainly is better than randomly generating the trees: You can use itertools to generate pairwise combinations and filter out duplicates and self-pointing loops:

```
import itertools

def make_all_trees(nodes):
    # generate all pairwise combinations of nodes
    edges =  [a for a in itertools.product(range(nodes), range(nodes))]

    # use sets to lose..
    # ..symmetric edges: (0,1), (1,0) => keep only (0,1) 
    edges = list(set([tuple(set(e)) for e in edges]))
    # ..and self-loops: (0,0)
    edges = [e for e in edges if len(e)>1]

    trees = []
    # generate all graphs that have nodes-1 edges
    for o in itertools.combinations(edges, nodes-1):
        #make sure that all nodes are in the edgelist:
        flattened = [item for sublist in o for item in sublist]

        if len(set(flattened)) == nodes:
            G = nx.Graph()
            G.add_edges_from(o)
            # make sure all nodes are connected
            if len(list(nx.connected_components(G)))==1:
                trees.append(G)

    return trees
```

#### testcases:

```
 len(make_all_trees(3)): 3
 len(make_all_trees(4)): 16
 len(make_all_trees(5)): 125
```

#### all 4 node trees:

trees = make_all_trees(4)

```
for p, tree in enumerate(trees):
    plt.subplot(4,4,p+1)
    nx.draw_networkx(tree)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This was really helpful, I got a question, so I tried to transform this trees to numpy arrays, the thing is that the matrix doesn't correspond to the graph, for example, for 3 trees I got the first two arrays right, but the last one is the same as the first, maybe if a ask another question you can help me?

Comment: @CarlosEduardoCorpus sure, go ahead. Seems weird that the last and the first should be the same.

Comment: Thank you! I just posted the question if you wanna check it out

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested in a more efficient approach that scales with larger n's then you can use a graph theory method called Prüfer sequences:

```
from sympy.combinatorics.prufer import Prufer
n = 8

max_trees = Prufer.unrank(0,n).size
trees = []
for i in range(max_trees):
    trees.append(Prufer.unrank(i,n).tree_repr)

print(len(trees))
#correctly returns n^(n-2) trees
```